# Angular add filter based on Object value

Tags: angularjs, filter, format

I'm starting AngularJS. I'm dynamically building a table with angular and I'm trying to add a filter to one of my columns.

Here the code I have in my controller :

```
$scope.columns = [
    {
        "alias":"alias1",
        "name":"name1",
        "type":"string"
    },
    {
        "alias":"alias2",
        "name":"name2",
        "type":"currency"
    }
];

$scope.data = [
    {
        "alias1": "value1",
        "alias2": "22489"
    },
    {
        "alias1": "value2",
        "alias2": "22489"
    },
    {
        "alias1": "value3",
        "alias2": "22489"
    },
];
```

And my table looks like this :

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="c in columns" ng-click="sort(c.alias)">{{ c.name }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in results | filter:search | orderBy:sortKey:reverse">
            <td ng-repeat="c in columns">{{ result[c.alias] }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I'd like to do is to apply a filter to the `<td>` value based on the `type` of the column. Something like `{{ result[c.alias] | c.type }}` doesn't work...

Is it something that can be achieved by some formatting directive for example ?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?:

```
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
    return function(input, param) {
        //do whatever
    }
})

{{ result[c.alias] | myfilter:c.type }}
```